# What is a layman's term for "uniform distribution

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, programming, statistics

I'm creating an implementation of a Lindenmayer system (L-system) in the Clojure programming language and I'm trying to figure out a name for a utility function which takes a number of arguments and then, using uniform distribution, chooses one of them. I'd like to appeal to non-mathematical/non-statistical readers by using a succinct function name which does not stray too far from the average person's vocabulary (soft goal, I know). Right now I've settled for "one-of", but I wonder if there is a more correct and easily understood term I could use.

By the way, if anyone wants to see the code in context, it is here: 
https://github.com/Reefersleep/l-mayer/blob/master/src/l_mayer/core.clj

The function implementation looks like this:

```
(defn one-of
  [& args]
  (let [random (rand-int (count args))]
    (get args random)))
```

And can be used like this:

```
(one-of :a :b :c)
```

In this usage, it would return either `:a`, `:b` or `:c`, with a 33,3% chance of each.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming functions is off topic

Comment: @matt-e-Эллен Where is this documented ? I had a look at http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask and thought this question falls safely into  "Word choice and usage" ?

Comment: Maybe it was a faux paus to mention _why_ I was interested in knowing what a layman's term for "uniform distribution" is , because so far, no one has attempted to answer it - rather, they relate their answers to the code. Though I appreciate these efforts, I am still interested in an answer to the original question and recognise that code naming may be off topic. I could edit the answer or reask it without mentioning the code aspect at all?

Comment: @k1eran if you look more closely in "on topic", naming things is in the off topic section.

Comment: @Reefersleep Our [tag:single-word-requests] tag description (click "learn more") gives a good outline for how to ask this sort of question. Feel free to edit this question to apply to those rules.

Comment: @Matt E. Эллен Okay cheers, I see that now.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен: Would it not be better to pose the edited question as a new one? I think the replies below would confuse future readers if I removed the original phrasing.

Comment: Sue, I have no objection to a new question.

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/388128/449347 where they use `pick-random` for a similar Clojure function.

Also that question has various other function names e.g.  `choose`.

I don't think this question is a total duplicate however, as this one is primarily about function naming, whereas the stack-overflow one is about function implementation/coding.

Comment: I appreciate the trove of suggestions in that thread :) And I may end up using something in that vein. But if possible, I would like to express the statistical aspect of "uniform distribution".

Answer (score 0):

If you primary goal is clarity then I would use a longer function name like **returnOneRandomArgument**.

If you don't think that connotes the uniform distribution idea, then maybe **pickOneArgumentFromHat** would work.

Comment: I think both of your suggestions relate to the randomness, but not in a clear enough way to the idea of uniform distribution - the relatable aspect of "from hat" is good, but I think it is misleading in a code context, where it could be misconstrued as a side effect.

Comment: @Reefersleep:  I understand your concern.  However, I think that to the layman "random" automatically means "random with a uniform distribution".  Perhaps you might work the word "bias" or "unbiased" into the function name (pickOneWithoutBias)?  I'm not sure that would make it any clearer though.

Comment: I think you're right about "random" implying uniform distribution. Perhaps such a thing as a layman's term for explicit uniform distribution in a random selection does not make sense _because_ it is normally implied. Adding "bias" is a good suggestion, but taking the above into account, I think it would be better to leave it out.